# What the /.. xpath does in a xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Look this xsl template:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:param name="bla" select="/.." />

    <ha>
        <xsl:value-of select="$bla" />
    </ha>
</xsl:template>
```

The part "select="/.." don't throw an exception (for me, the right xpath is ../), but does nothing.

Why define a parameter like that ?

If i execute the template without pass the "bla" parameter, "ha" will be empty, otherwise it will contain the value passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The part "select="/.." don't throw an exception (for me, the right
>   xpath is ../), but does nothing.
>
> Why define a parameter like that ?

**This is useful in XSLT 1.0** to indicate that the type of an `xsl:param` or an `xsl:variable` is node-set.

Then the XSLT processor will not produce an error on expression like:

```
$bla | $myNodeSet
```

**On the contrary, if you just define the parameter without giving it any default value, the expression above produces an error** -- sometnhing like:

"*Expression must evaluate to a node-set*"

**Easy verification**:

**Try this** (works OK):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:param name="blah" select="/.."/>

 <xsl:copy-of select=". | $blah"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and this** (results in error):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:param name="blah"/>

 <xsl:copy-of select=". | $blah"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed a pretty useless thing to try. You're selecting the parent of the root node, which has no parent node by definition. Use the following to show that nothing is selected:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($bla)"/>
```

Output:

```
<ha>0</ha>
```

Comment: lwburk: actually, that is a pretty useful thing in some cases -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a mistake in the query and xslt ingnores invalid parts of queries.